# Excel Index Match Find Row Where Column Meets Criteria and Greater than 0

Tags: excel, indexing, match, multiple-columns

I have a data set in Excel that represents names and job IDs on the Y-axis, and days of the week on the X-axis. Occasionally a name will float to other job IDs but a name will never have more than one job ID per day. I am attempting to find the job ID while inputting the name and day of the week, finding the job with a value > 0.

[image: Example]

So far, I am using `=INDEX(B2:G9,MATCH(J2,A2:A9,0),MATCH(J3,C1:G1,0))` with the simplified example, but this always returns the first match, and I am not sure how to narrow it down to the row having value > 0. In the example above, I am expecting G1 for Job ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you can find a working formula (though not too elegant):

```
=INDEX(B2:B9,MATCH(1,(J2=A2:A9)*(0<IFS(J3=C1,C2:C9,J3=D1,D2:D9,J3=E1,E2:E9,J3=F1,F2:F9,J3=G1,G2:G9)),0))
```

[Here](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria) is the refernce for the index-match with multiple criteria.

Comment: Thanks! This worked in my simplified example. I will try to apply to the real-world scenario (days of week in a full month with other data points rather than an entry form) and see if this will work. As you mentioned, not as elegant as I was hoping for (easier maintenance for the next guy) but gets the job done.

Comment: Update: I was able to apply this logic pattern to the real-world scenario without issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to use the **FILTER** and **INDEX** functions.

Breaking the approach down into separate steps before combining the formulas into a single mega formula.
Then offering a simplification of the formula using the **LET** function.

[image]

### Filter based on the name.

`=FILTER(A1:G9,(A1:A9=J2)+(A1:A9="Name"))`

The plus symbol (**+**) used in **include** portion of the formula acts as an **OR** function.
It is used to bring the headings row into the results.

[image]

### Filter based on day

`=FILTER(A12#,(INDEX(A12#,,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})=J3)+(INDEX(A12#,,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})="Job Id"))`

The results of the previous formula are referred to using a cell reference and a hash (**A12#**) to select the cell and the spill area.
The **INDEX** function is used with filter the spill range before applying the criteria.  The array **{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}** refers the seven column headings.
The plus symbol (**+**) is used again as an **OR** function.
It is used to bring the **Job Id** column into the results.

[image]

### Filter based on hours

`=FILTER(A18#,(INDEX(A18#,,2)<>0))`

The results of the previous formula are referred to using a cell reference and a hash (**A18#**) to select the cell and the spill area.
The **INDEX** function is used to filter the spill range before applying the criteria.

[image]

### Get the results

`=INDEX(A24#,2,1)`

Use the **INDEX** function to retrieve the first column, second row from the results.

[image]

### Mega formula

Putting all the steps into a single formula.

`=INDEX(FILTER(FILTER(FILTER(A1:G9,(A1:A9=J2)+(A1:A9="Name")),(INDEX(FILTER(A1:G9,(A1:A9=J2)+(A1:A9="Name")),,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})=J3)+(INDEX(FILTER(A1:G9,(A1:A9=J2)+(A1:A9="Name")),,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})="Job Id")),(INDEX(FILTER(FILTER(A1:G9,(A1:A9=J2)+(A1:A9="Name")),(INDEX(FILTER(A1:G9,(A1:A9=J2)+(A1:A9="Name")),,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})=J3)+(INDEX(FILTER(A1:G9,(A1:A9=J2)+(A1:A9="Name")),,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})="Job Id")),,2)<>0)),2,1)`

Not very easy to read or maintain.

### Use LET

To simplify the formula, use the **LET** function to calculate each of the steps.
The **name** portion of the formula is used to clearly identify each step.
If an invalid parameter is used, instead of a **#CALC** error, the text *Invalid Selection* is displayed.

```
=LET(
NameFilter,
  FILTER(A1:G9,(A1:A9=J2)+(A1:A9="Name")),
DayFilter,
  FILTER(NameFilter,(INDEX(NameFilter,,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})=J3)+(INDEX(NameFilter,,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})="Job Id")),
HourFilter,
  FILTER(DayFilter,(INDEX(DayFilter,,2)<>0)),
Result,
  INDEX(HourFilter,2,1),
IFERROR(Result,"Invalid Selection")
)
```

[image]